# IBM MQ Spring Boot JMS Reconnection after application sleep

Tags: spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq

I have a Spring Boot JavaFX application (fat client) which connects to IBM MQ using Spring Boot JMS (JmsTemplate: easy configuration-leave it up to Spring Boot).
I have set the following in application.properties:

```
ibm.mq.queueManager = queuemanager
ibm.mq.channel = channel I am using
ibm.mq.connName = server to connect to
ibm.mq.user = user name
ibm.mq.password= the password
ibm.mq.queue = the queue to use
ibm.mq.reconnect=QMGR
```

Trace log shows the following when the application starts:

```
2024-01-25 11:48:17:151 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - constructor
2024-01-25 11:48:17:161 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConnectionFactoryConfiguration - Creating caching MQConnectionFactory
2024-01-25 11:48:17:163 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConnectionFactoryFactory - constructor
2024-01-25 11:48:17:163 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConnectionFactoryFactory - createConnectionFactory for class MQConnectionFactory
2024-01-25 11:48:17:163 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationSslBundles - SSLBundles are not supported
2024-01-25 11:48:17:163 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConnectionFactoryFactory - configuring TLS Store system properties
2024-01-25 11:48:17:163 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConnectionFactoryFactory - createConnectionFactoryInstance for class MQConnectionFactory
2024-01-25 11:48:17:342 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConnectionFactoryFactory - configureConnectionFactory
2024-01-25 11:48:17:342 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - queueManager    : XX_XXX_X
2024-01-25 11:48:17:342 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - applicationName : null
2024-01-25 11:48:17:342 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - ccdtUrl         : null
2024-01-25 11:48:17:342 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - channel         : THE_CHANNEL
2024-01-25 11:48:17:342 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - clientId        : null
2024-01-25 11:48:17:342 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - connName        : THE_MQ_SERVER
2024-01-25 11:48:17:342 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - reconnectOption : 'QMGR' [0x04000000]
2024-01-25 11:48:17:342 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - sslCipherSpec   : null
2024-01-25 11:48:17:342 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - sslCipherSuite  : null
2024-01-25 11:48:17:342 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - sslKeyresetcount: -1
2024-01-25 11:48:17:342 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - sslPeerName     : null
2024-01-25 11:48:17:342 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - sslBundle       : null
2024-01-25 11:48:17:342 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - tempModel       : null
2024-01-25 11:48:17:343 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - tempQPrefix     : null
2024-01-25 11:48:17:343 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - tempTopicPrefix : null
2024-01-25 11:48:17:343 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - user            : 'XXXXXX'
2024-01-25 11:48:17:343 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - password set    : YES
2024-01-25 11:48:17:343 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - sslFIPSRequired        : false
2024-01-25 11:48:17:343 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - useIBMCipherMappings   : true
2024-01-25 11:48:17:343 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - userAuthenticationMQCSP: true
2024-01-25 11:48:17:343 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - outboundSNI            : ''
2024-01-25 11:48:17:343 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - channelSharing         : ''
2024-01-25 11:48:17:343 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - balancingAppType       : '' [0]
2024-01-25 11:48:17:343 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - balancingTimeout       : '' [-1]
2024-01-25 11:48:17:343 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - balancingOptions       : '' [0]
2024-01-25 11:48:17:343 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - jndiCF          : null
2024-01-25 11:48:17:343 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - jndiProviderUrl : null
2024-01-25 11:48:17:343 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - JKS keystore           : null
2024-01-25 11:48:17:343 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - JKS keystore pw set    : NO
2024-01-25 11:48:17:343 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - JKS truststore         : null
2024-01-25 11:48:17:343 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - JKS truststore pw set  : NO
2024-01-25 11:48:17:343 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - No additional properties defined
2024-01-25 11:48:17:343 TRACE c.i.m.s.b.MQConfigurationProperties - Pooling is disabled
```

All is well when the application is running. Now, we have users that do not close the application when they close the lid of their laptop. When they then open the laptop to continue working in the application, reconnect fails...

The following is showing in the log:

```
nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: 
IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2556' ('MQRC_RECONNECT_TIMED_OUT').
```

The only way to recover is to restart the application, after that all is well again. Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The default auto-reconnect timeout is 1800 seconds (30 minutes) after which it'll give up. The error message is pretty clear that that's what you are seeing.

If you want to increase the timeout, then - for now - you have to explicitly set it yourself. It's not an exposed external config option in the Spring Boot Starter. Though I am hoping for it to be added in a future version.

To set it, you'd need a customize method for the CF. And in that, do

```
  cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT,3600); // an hour
```

Comment: Mark, thanks for your advice. The issue is that the reconnect doesn't work, even though the MQ server is available. When the user restarts the application, connection is available and everything works as expected. I think it has something to do with the laptop waking up after sleep mode (and the application was open when the laptop lid was closed). I just can't figure out what to do to get the reconnect to work.